# How to print numpy objects without line breaks

Tags: python, logging, numpy

I am logging input arguments to a function using

```
logging.debug('Input to this function = %s',
              inspect.getargvalues(inspect.currentframe())[3])
```

But I do not want the line breaks inserted within numpy objects.  `numpy.set_printoptions(linewidth=np.nan)` removes some, but line breaks are still inserted in 2D objects such as

```
array([[ 0.84148239,  0.71467895,  0.00946744,  0.3471317 ],
       [ 0.68041249,  0.20310698,  0.89486761,  0.97799646],
       [ 0.22328803,  0.32401271,  0.96479887,  0.43404245]])
```

I want it to be like this:

```
array([[ 0.84148239,  0.71467895,  0.00946744,  0.3471317 ], [ 0.68041249,  0.20310698,  0.89486761,  0.97799646], [ 0.22328803,  0.32401271,  0.96479887,  0.43404245]])
```

How can I do this?  Thanks.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more why the `inspect` module is used here? Can't you just pass the numpy array in question directly to the logging module, as `logging.debug("some text %s" , str(array))` or something similar? Otherwise, what is the type of  `inspect.getargvalues(inspect.currentframe())[3]`?

Comment: Because I want to log automatically all the arguments to a function.  (Some of them are numpy objects.)  When I add or remove arguments, this line doesn't have to change.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Given an array `x`, you can print it without line breaks with,

```
import numpy as np
x_str = np.array_repr(x).replace('\n', '')
print(x_str)
```

or alternatively using the function `np.array2string` instead of `np.array_repr`.

I'm not sure if there is an easy way to remove newlines from the string representation or numpy arrays. However, it is always possible to remove them after the conversion took place,

```
input_args = inspect.getargvalues(inspect.currentframe())[3]
logging.debug('Input to this function = %s', repr(input_args).replace('\n', ''))
```

Comment: @spark I updated the answer above to account for the logging.

Comment: This works.  I would use `repr` instead of `str` though.

Comment: in short, if you imported numpy, it's just `x.replace('\n', '')`

Answer (score 13):

```
import numpy as np
np.set_printoptions(threshold=np.inf)
np.set_printoptions(linewidth=np.inf)

# Testing:
big_arr = np.ones([30,70])
print(big_arr)
```

Comment: To add some more info, the `threshold` is the "Total number of array elements which trigger summarization rather than full repr". See [here](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.set_printoptions.html) for the docs.

Comment: Does not work on Python 3.12/numpy 1.24.4, i.e. you still get line breaks after each row, i.e. `len(str(big_arr).splitlines())` evaluates to `30` ....

Answer (score 1):

Simple solution

```py
import numpy as np
value = np.array([[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8], [1, 2, 3, 7, 8]])

value_str = str(value).replace('\n', '')  

print("prints: " + value_str)
# prints: [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8], [1, 2, 3, 7, 8]]
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution also works:

```
myArray = np.array([[ 0.84148239,  0.71467895,  0.00946744,  0.3471317 ],
       [ 0.68041249,  0.20310698,  0.89486761,  0.97799646],
       [ 0.22328803,  0.32401271,  0.96479887,  0.43404245]])

print(np.array2string(myArray).replace('\n','').replace(' ',', '))
```

Output:

```
[[0.84148239, 0.71467895, 0.00946744, 0.3471317, ], [0.68041249, 0.20310698, 0.89486761, 0.97799646], [0.22328803, 0.32401271, 0.96479887, 0.43404245]]
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).